# Set Multiple RowFilters On JXTable

Tags: java, filter, swingx, rowfilter, jxtable

How can i add more than one filter for 1 Row in JXTable?

I tried using:

```
int col = jxTable.getColumn("Tipo").getModelIndex();
RowFilter filter1 = RowFilters.regexFilter(0, "^N", col)
RowFilter filter2 = RowFilters.regexFilter(0, "^N", col)

jxTable.setRowFilter(filter1);
jxTable.setRowFilter(filter2);
```

but `filter2` overwrites the `filter1`

the usage:

I will do 3 checks box with different letters to filter,

```
[ ]A  [ ]B  [ ]C
```

if you check A, just show what start with A, if you check B and A, display both...

Answer (score 4):

Use the `RowFilter.andFilter()` or `RowFilter.orFilter()` methods when you want to combine more than one filter. For your situation, it sounds like you want to use the `orFilter` method

**Steps:**

- Take all the filters you want to add to the table and put them in a list
- call `RowFilter.andFilter()` or `RowFilter.orFilter()` to create a single filter  that `AND`s or `OR`s the filters from the list.
- Apply the newly created `AND` or `OR` filter created to the JXTable.

**Example:**

```
//Code not tested
int col = jxTable.getColumn("Tipo").getModelIndex();
RowFilter filter1 = RowFilters.regexFilter(0, "^N", col)
RowFilter filter2 = RowFilters.regexFilter(0, "^N", col)

List<RowFilter> filters = new ArrayList<RowFilter>();
filters.add(filter1);
filters.add(filter2)
RowFilter orFilter = RowFilter.orFilter(filters);
jxTable.setRowFilter(orFilter);
```